# Perl regex to globally insert newline before pattern match

Tags: regex, perl, global

I am struggling to insert a newline before a matching string that consists of a period followed by 2 or 3 characters (alphanumeric) and ending with another period. If possible, this needs to be a single statement that acts upon an entire file.

Something like (?):

```
$contents =~ s/\.{2,3}\./\n\.<what goes here?>\./g;
```

Specifically, I am dealing with a file of many catalog records in a 2-step process.
Step 1: removing all carriage returns from the file.
Step 2: finding text strings such as .AUTH. and .RE. and even .856. and making each of these the beginning of a new line. I can do this with a long series of specific substitutions,

```
$contents=~s/\.RE\./\n\.RE\./g;
$contents=~s/\.AUTH\./\n\.AUTH\./g;
$contents=~s/\.TITL\./\n\.TITL\./g;
```

But my understanding is that I can also do this more efficiently with a single statement (using regex built-in variables?)

Thanks,

Thom

Comment: The `.` characters do not have to be escaped in the replacement strings.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all new-line characters use

```
$contents =~ s/\n//g;
```

To add desired new-line characters use

```
$contents =~ s/(?=[.][a-z\d]{2,3}[.])/\n/ig;
```

Comment: This worked okay for the numbers but did nothing for the letters. In other words, the .856. strings were preceded by a newline, not, say, the .AUTH. lines.

Comment: @ThomasShepard - Sure it does not work with `.AUTH.`, as you have been asked for 2-3 alphanumeric characters string and `AUTH` has 4 characters. Simple math, right? So who is wrong? If you need to go up to 4 characters, then change `{2,3}` to `{2,4}` and you should be good to go...

Comment: Gee, is my face red! Of course, you are correct, and yes, it does work now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ThomasShepard - Finally you find out who is wrong and who is right. So please, now, accept my solution/answer (I hope you know how to do that). Thank you and good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$contents =~ s/(\.\w{2,3}\.)/\n$1/;
```

Use parenthesis to remember the matching string and $1 to refer to it in the substitution part.

Comment: The solution does what you asked for: "insert a newline before a matching string that consists of a period followed by 2 or 3 characters (alphanumeric) and ending with another period", thus I don't understand the negative vote. If you prefer other solutions is fine, but at least don't vote negatively something that works.